# Why is overriding a method not exactly the same as not overriding a method?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, overriding

So I was working in my Xamarin project and came across this small little "feature":

```
public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
{
    base.Draw(rect);
}
```

Draws a black box at the place of the view (what this exactly does is irrelevant to the question).

Whereas this code:

```
//public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
//{
//    base.Draw(rect);
//}
```

Draws a transparent box (again the exact outcome of the method is irrelevant to the question).

Now I would like to know (on the level of C#) how these 2 implementations differ. In my understanding these 2 pieces of code are functionally identical, but they are obviously not, as they cause 2 different outcomes.

What is going on?

Comment: The second one is uncommented and not compiled at all meaning it doesn´t exist within your executing code.

Comment: Yes but in my understanding these should be functionally identical, as I override a base method with itself.

Comment: I think the question being asked is why simply calling the base.Draw in the overridden method with no changes is somehow getting a different result from not overriding it at all.

Comment: It shouldn't. It should produce the exact same result, unless the caller gets the method info by reflection and gets the DeclaringType of the method and does something with reflection to invoke a non-virtual method (including property getters) on that declaring type explicitly to get the fill brush. This as very interesting otherwise.

Comment: Which object are you extending?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I am extending a `UIView`.

Comment: Without seeing the base class code it is impossible to understand what is causing this. Are there any side effects in the base class, e.g., synchronisation between threads etc?

Comment: Do you have any properties or methods that hide any base members in your class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a pure C# perspective, these two methods should behave identically 99.9999% of the time. It's possible for the caller to determine if a certain method is overridden, and execute a different code path, but that's cumbersome and just not something people do in C#.

However in Objective-C it is much easier (and in fact a common idiom) to check if a method is implemented before calling it.

This means that if Objective-C does something like this:

```
if ([obj respondsToSelector: @selector (drawRect:)])
    [obj drawRect: theRect];
else
    [obj doSomethingElse];
```

you can end up with the behavior you're seeing (since the first case would end up in your overridden code).

Comment: Yes, but even then, it should always run that first code, since it is implemented in the base class anyway, as it always responds to the selector.

Comment: In Xamarin.iOS, only methods that are explicitly overwritten are reported back to the Objective-C runtime, even if there is a "base" method.